# Best way to structure data to support only showing records a user has not seen

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Say you have a collection of videos and you would like to track what users has seen those videos and make certain that the users do not see those videos again or at bare minimum prioritize videos that a user hasn't seen above those that they have seen.  What would be the best way to accomplish this that would scale?

In SQL I would typically use a left join to accomplish this and start by eliminating videos that the user has seen, but even this could start to decline in performance.  I know that I should be able to do this by creating two collections.  One for the videos and one for the views and use a lookup, but I wasn't sure if there was a better/more performant way to accomplish this task.

Comment: Creating two collections would be most likely a poor design. Put it all in one collection and write view counter as embedded document.

Comment: The count of views isn't necessarily what I'm most concerned with,. it is more users that have viewed the video.  As the count of users could be in the millions, my concern is would having an array of users that have viewed the video have more of a negative impact on the performance of returning the videos than storing it in a separate collection and doing a lookup in to the data.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should store data about views in the same collection as movies:

```
const movies = [{
  id: 123,
  title: "Titanic",
  usersViewed: [1001, 1002]
}]
```

You can simply create (multikey) index on `userViewed` field to easily filter user values.

If the `userViewed` list starts growing, and you don't need the data for regular movies querying, you can store it in separate collection. Regular queries on movies would be faster, but for filtering based on views you would need to do extra `$lookup`. Index on `userId` will help again.

```
const usersViewed = [{
  movieId: 123,
  userId: 1001 
}, {
  movieId: 123,
  userId: 1002
}]
```

Comment: It seems like you would have the same concern as I would with usersViewed being stored in the same document as the moview.  We could be talking about hundreds of thousands to millions of views on a single video.  Would it be safe to assume storing that amount of values in the usersViewed array would hurt performance more than the lookup would?

Comment: @LarryBeall Unfortunately I am not so experienced to determine the exact threshold when using separate collection is more performant.